# Trouble with converting regex to python

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex

```
[^\\]["'&<>]
```

in order to match some unescaped characters. However trying to convert it into a python string is giving me grief. I've tried

```
r'[^\\][\"\'&<>]'
```

but I end up with this error.

```
raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad group name
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why `r` when you have escaped everythin with ` \ ` ... Or do you wanna match ` \ ` also?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you doing something wrong?

```
import re

print(bool(re.match(r'[^\\]["\'&<>]', 'a\"a')))    # True
print(bool(re.match(r'[^\\]["\'&<>]', 'asd')))     # False
```

Answer (score 0):

As your pattern contain `'` and `"` you need to use 3 double quote `"""` and use `re.escape` to convert to a string :

```
>>> print re.escape("""[^\\]["'&<>] """)
\[\^\\\]\[\"\'\&\<\>\]\
```